# How to show checkbox checked if data is saved in database using "AngularJS"?

Tags: php, angularjs, sugarcrm, checklist-model

I am working with `SugarCRM` API for `get_module_fields`and displaying its results in  Checkbox [You can check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJIey.png) . I have saved some checkbox  value in database using `AngularJS` `checklist-model` and now I want to update it.So for that I want to display saved checkbox as checked but I unable to do that.Is any one can tell me how to do that?
here is my script code and i dont know what to write in `$scope.users.mod_fields` so that i can display checked checkbox

```js
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.users = {};
 $scope.users.mod_name = '<?php echo $module_name;?>';
 $scope.users.mod_id = '<?php echo $module_id;?>';
 $scope.users.mod_fields ='';
 $scope.updateModule=function(){  
    $http.post("update_modulelist.php", {'mod_id':$scope.users.mod_id,'mod_name':$scope.users.mod_name,  'mod_fields' : $scope.users.mod_fields})
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
     alert(JSON.stringify(data));
      //alert("Data Inserted Successfully");
      window.location.href="show_modulelist.php";
    });
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: use `ngChecked`. If you post more code, maybe someone could help you

Comment: Too broad. But in general you need to use ngModel directive on the checkbox and initialize model accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done like this & got perfect answer:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.users = {
  mod_fields: '<?php foreach ($items as $key=>$val) { echo $val.',';}?>'
 };
 $scope.users.mod_name = '<?php echo $module_name;?>';
 $scope.users.mod_id = '<?php echo $module_id;?>';
 $scope.users.mod_fields =  <?php
                    $module_fields = $_GET['fields']; 
     $module_fie =explode(',',$module_fields);
     json_encode($module_fie);
                    echo json_encode($module_fie) ?>;
 $scope.updateModule=function(users){  
    $http.post("update_modulelist.php", {'mod_id':$scope.users.mod_id,'mod_name':$scope.users.mod_name,  'mod_fields' : $scope.users.mod_fields})
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
      window.location.href="show_modulelist.php";
    });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't put the HTML code, but to update this, you actually need to modify the checklistModel, not ngChecked or ngModel.

Comment: Sir, I am new in angularjs and i dont know how to perform this. Could you please tell me

Comment: Pretty much like you did, but in the success function you need to modify the checklistModel like `$scope.listModel= ...`.